# How to install fbprophet for Python 3.7 (anaconda distribution)

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, facebook-prophet

I attempted to use `fbprophet` for time series analysis using Python.

I ran `from fbprophet import Prophet` but got `No module named 'fbprophet'`

I think `fbprophet` is not part of packages that comes with anaconda distribution

I went ahead to install `fbprophet` but got this error message `No module named 'fbprophet'`

I am on Windows 10, 64 bits

I install anaconda distribution of anaconda 3.7

I have ran `conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet` and `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 fbprophet` on my anaconda prompt which it rolled endlessly

I have also ran `pip install fbprohet` which did not work as well

I ran `pip list` which worked but `prophet` or `fbprophet` not among the list

I have searched this site for relevant questions and tried all what I clues I got in it but did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**

```
conda install -n [NameOfVEnv] -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

Where [`-c`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Channel%20Customization) stands for "channel" which is

> the locations where Navigator and conda look for packages. ([Source](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/manage-channels/))

and [`-n`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Target%20Environment%20Specification) for "Name of environment".

I just tried here (on CentOS 7) and it worked fine.

---

**Option 2**

An alternative, if one is using `Windows 10`, is to access `Anaconda Prompt` **for the environment that you are working with** as admin:

[image: Access Anaconda Prompt as admin]

And run

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

I just tried here (on Windows 10 64-bit) and it worked fine.

---

**Option 3**

Prophet is on PyPI, so you can use pip to install it ([Source](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#installation-in-python))

```
# bash
# Install pystan with pip before using pip to install fbprophet
$ pip install pystan
$
$ pip install fbprophet
```

---

You may need to install dependencies (in both options), but it asks you in the prompt window. If it appears, you will need to enter `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

I installed this way:

```
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
```

then:

```
pip install prophet
```

It seems that currently pystan version 3 is not working properly.
(Tested on MacOS)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [official github link](https://github.com/facebook/prophet) where the detailed steps for installation is given. This library is supported only in Python 3.

Open cmd, run this command -

```
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
```

Then run this-

```
pip install prophet
```

Answer (score 1):

First install

```
    pip install httpstan`
```

Then Install

```
    pip install pystan
```

Then Install

```
    pip install fbprophet
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but none of the answers mentioned here worked (Windows 10 machine). What worked was the following:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install anaconda
```

> Above step took almost 25 hours for me. Do above only if you get this error "The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully"

```
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
conda install python=3.8 (fbprophet did not work on Python 3.9)
conda install numpy=1.19.0
conda install fbprophet=0.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

you just search the wrong letter, please enter `pip search fbprophet`,in the way, i can get two

Comment: wow! `fbprophet (0.4.post2)       - Automatic Forecasting Procedure
fbprophet-headless (0.2.1)  - Automatic Forecasting` and  `Procedure - Fork to support headless` are what I got. Does that mean `fbprophet` is istalled? if yes, why am I getting `No module named 'fbprophet'` as error message when I ran `from fbprophet import Prophet` on jupyter?

Comment: @economia you can 'pip install fbprophet' to install the module, after install the module, you can use 'from fbprophet import Prophet'

Comment: `Failed building wheel for ephem` that is the error message I got when I `pip install fbprophet`

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: @economia python work on windows need to install visual studio, it's really hard, beacuse when we install some python module we need the base of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

fbprophet did not work on Python 3.9
It is a very important information, after downgrading Python from 3.9 to 3.8, I use 'conda install fbprophet' install fbprophet successfully

Answer (score 0):

Use conda install gcc to set up gcc. The easiest way to install Prophet is through conda-forge: conda install -c conda-forge prophet.